# How to access strings entered in loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code.

```
n = int(input("Enter number of strings: "))
for i in range(n):
    ai= input("Enter string ")
i=0
print(ai)
```

- Why does it give last string and not the first string?
- If I try to print a0 ,it gives error.

I know that I can use lists , but I didn't know about list when I wrote the program and now I have to change everything to use list.

Comment: Yeah, you need to change the program to use a list.

Comment: Is this for school? What results were you expecting?

Comment: "change everything"? You need to either store your inputted data in some kind of datastructure _or_ you have to digest/process it immediately, before it is overwritten by the next input. you can put a `l = []` before your for-loop and a `l.append(ai)` after you questioned for the string. You can process the list after the inputs this way. Beside that, I highly recommend using / working with https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ to learn the basics. SO is not really good at "teaching" those, we are more for when you already have some basic knowledge and got a snag in your programm

Comment: You know you need list. Now go to docs or tutorials and learn how to use lists.

Comment: This is for my college. I was expecting to get first string. Why do I get error when I print (a0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are overwriting the variable in each iteration of the loop, if you want to print all the strings added in the format you can use something like this

```
n = int(input('enter number of strings'));
ai = ''
for i in range(n):
   ai += input('enter a string: ')+'\n'
i = 0
print(ai)
```

This will print your string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list and append every input to the list instead:

```
n = int(input("Enter number of strings: "))
a = []
for _ in range(n):
    a.append(input("Enter string: "))
print(a[0])
```

Comment: I think I should change everything now. Thanks for the answer. Which tutorial is best to study python?

Comment: You're welcome. You can start with the official tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/